*ngIf and ngmodel is not working on .html pages
I'm using following versions in Angular, Angular CLI: 17.3.4, Node: 20.9.0, Package Manager: npm 10.5.2. When I'm using *ngIf or ngmodel on .html pages in a component, I'm getting following error message that it is not supporting them.

NG8103: The *ngIf directive was used in the template, but neither the NgIf directive nor the CommonModule was imported. Use Angular's built-in control flow @if or make sure that either the NgIf directive or the CommonModule is included in the @Component.imports array of this component.
Can I know is it because of the Angular version? Because of that I can't sent data or get data from backend.

I tried following code,
<input type="email" id="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="Enter your email" class="form-control" required>
Because I got error I used following code <div *ngIf="email.errors?.['required']">Email is required.</div>
But this does not succeed connecting with backend.

This error is telling you that while you're trying to use the *ngIf directive in your template, the NgIf directive or CommonModule has not been correctly imported into the component using it. Angular's move towards optional NgModules means that each standalone component needs to explicitly declare its dependencies.
To fix this issue, you need to ensure that CommonModule (which includes NgIf, ngFor, etc.) is imported into your component or that your component is declared with the necessary imports. Here’s how you can adjust your component setup.
Maybe something like :
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-selector',
  templateUrl: './your-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.scss'],
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule] // Import CommonModule here
})
export class YourComponent {
  // Your component logic here
}

or
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { YourComponent } from './path/to/your.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [YourComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule, // For template-driven forms
    ReactiveFormsModule // For reactive forms
  ],
  exports: [YourComponent]
})
export class YourModule {}

in case NgModule is a traditional Module.
